# How to programmatically setting phone to vibrate only?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, vibration

For phones with Marshmallow and below, I've been able to use

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

I learned thanks to another StackOverflow user that with Nougat and above, you use the following code to allow the app to mess with Do Not Disturb settings.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings
                        .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

However, I'm unable to set the phone to vibrate only. The `audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);` part silences the phone instead of setting it to vibrate only. Is this now outdated? How do I do this in Nougat?

Comment: What do you want it to vibrate for? If it's for a notification, it can be done in an easier way than that.

Comment: @user2638180 For incoming texts and calls, I'm assuming incoming notifications as well. Whatever it usually vibrates for when the phone's in vibrate mode